# Generate a QEMU bootable kernel from an existing installation

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, osx, console, qemu

I have been trying to setup QEMU to provide console output only. So far I have succeeded with the following parameters: `qemu-system -curses -hda debian.img`, where debian.img is a working Debian installation. No other boot related parameters are used. (N)Curses seems to be terribly buggy and slow for this purpose however, at least under a macOS host.

I found out that a better way to achieve console, non-gui output to the terminal that qemu is launched in by using `-serial stdio -append "console=ttyAMA0"` instead of `-curses`. This option requires you to specify a kernel with the `-kernel` parameter however. Is there a way I can extract a bootable kernel from my existing Debian installation that I can provide to qemu? I already tried copying vmlinux from `/boot`, and also followed [this guide](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/03/08/how-to-extract-and-disassmble-a-linux-kernel-image-vmlinuz/) to extract the kernel from the OS, but they won't boot under QEMU with my existing debian.img file. I believe I possibly have to supply the initrd.img from my OS to qemu as well.

Now, is it possible to keep using my exisiting debian.img file with a fully working OS on it, while also passing an (extracted) kernel from that image (or elsewhere if needed) to qemu using the `-kernel` parameter? (and the same question for the initrd.img file) 
My guest OS on the debian.img file is Debian Jessy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use direct kernel booting (via the `-kernel` QEMU option), you almost certainly want to provide the `-initrd` as well. They can be copied from the `/boot` directory of the running emulated system, or you can use `losetup` and `kpartx` to make the partitions of the image file mountable (and make sure to umount them before you start the emulated system again). Generally you'll also have to `-append "root=/dev/sda2 console=ttyAMA0"` or similar.

An alternative way is to append the necessary kernel parameter to the boot loader configuration in the image. It's less flexible, but maybe you don't actually need all the flexibility of `-append`. You may need to run `update-grub` or something similar to get your `console` parameter embedded into the actual boot menu. Run `cat /proc/cmdline` in the booted system to check if it's really in effect.

You'll need `-serial stdio` in either case, but replace it by `-nographic` once you don't need the graphical window anymore.

Comment: My question mostly concerns exactly how the initial ram disk and the kernel  should be exported, as I was not able to find a good way to do this. From your answer I understand that they can be exported from the running system, is this done by just copying them from /boot? (i.e. copying /boot/vmlinuz and /boot/initrd.img to my host) 

I will look into the second method now as well.

Comment: if I just copy them from /boot the qemu app window comes with "Booting from rom..." and then "Booting from EDD... ok" and then freezes. The terminal I launch qemu in shows nothing.

Comment: As for the alternative, I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the "necessary kernel parameter", but appending the rule "console=ttyAMA0" to both /boot/cmdline.txt and /etc/grub/defaults and removing the `-append` parameter from the qemu invocation leads to the qemu GUI starting without any output to the terminal (or input for that matter).

(invocation: `qemu-system-x86_64  -hda debian.img`)

Comment: You still need to provide a serial port via `-serial stdio`. Please always show the full command line you're experimenting with.

Comment: Any insights in why copying them from /boot and starting with `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -kernel vmlinuz  -initrd  initrd.img ` won't work? (this first suggestion is still part of your answer, I will try  appending `-serial stdio` together with alternative you suggested) (`file vmlinuz` shows that it is a boot executable bzImage btw)

Comment: Retrying your second suggestion but this time making sure to append `-serial stdio` did not work out again. To recap, I tried to edit both /boot/cmdline.txt (adding console=ttyAMA0) and change my grub bootloader settings (in /etc/default/grub) by appending 'console=ttyAMA0'  to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter. I then started qemu with `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -serial stdio `

Comment: I tried the first approach again after your last edits. The first invocation I tried is: 
`qemu-system-x86_64  -hda debian.img -kernel vmlinuz -initrd initrd.img -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyAMA0"` I assigned root to `/dev/sda1` because that is the first device that shows in `/etc/fstab`, but I tried numerous other devices as well. I repeated the same process, but this time I replaced `-serial stdio` with `-nographic`, again with no luck. 
Have you tested any of this yourself recently? I think I once came across the `-nographic` option being outdated somewhere.

Comment: (continuation of my previous comment) The only thing that happened in all cases is that the GUI popped up with the exact same message as in my second comment.

Comment: Second approach: for some reason I am unable to change the contents of /proc/cmdline. Some of my `/etc/defaults/grub` contents appear, but not all of them: `$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=UUID=ff0bca2b-0d....  ro fbcon=map:99 text` (the UUID is `/dev/sda1`)

However, if I boot up and press 'e'  to edit to edit my grub settings manually, my "console=" rule does show up. I also know the changes to grub come through due to the fact that if I append "console=ttyAMA0" to my kernel boot options the system won't get very far in booting (no errors though).

Comment: The relevant lines of my `/etc/defaults/grub` file look as follows and I've made sure to run `sudo update-grub` after every change:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fbcon=map:99 text console=ttyAMA0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" 
(I tried to append the `console= ttyAMA0 ` rule to both grub options but the result is the same) And as you said, I launch qemu with `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img  -serial stdio` after making the changes to grub.

Comment: Can you share your image file? Being able to influence your kernel command line is critical. Also, `ttyAMA0` is an ARM AMBA serial device, so `qemu-system-x86_64` probably won't emulate it. Try `console=ttyS0` instead. Also note that unless your serial driver is compiled in, you won't see early kernel messages (those before the module is loaded) on the serial console.

Comment: Side note: `qemu-system-arm` should be able to emulate `ttyAMA` devices, but you apparently have an x86 image. Also, it's possible to provide multiple `console=` arguments to the Linux kernel, and it will use all of them simultaneously. Only the last one becomes the user space console, though.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed did the trick. Thanks for the tip on how on how only `qemu-system-arm` can emulate ttyAMA, my confusion came from the fact that this did seem to work on my arm setup. 
As a further reference, the following qemu invocation seemed to work to get the guest output to appear "natively" in the macOS terminal (`-serial stdio` handling host keyboard input in more annoying ways):
`qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic -hda debian.img -kernel vmlinuz -initrd initrd.img -append 'root=/dev/sda1 console=ttyS0'`, where the value of root is the partition you boot from.

Comment: As you said, you might be able to omit the `-append` command line flag if you get these settings properly embedded in your kernel command line.

Comment: More precisely: if you get the bootloader in your image file pass the `console=ttyS0` parameter to the kernel it boots, you won't need any of the `-kernel`, `-initrd` and `-append` command line flags. The `-kernel` flag switches to *direct kernel* boot, circumventing the boot loader in the image. `-initrd` and `-append` are relevant in this mode only. If you boot via the firmware, the information is provided by the bootloader configuration in the image.